# shorting mysql query with more performance

Tags: php, mysql

How can I shorten this query?

```
SET sql_mode = '';
SELECT t1.`id_number`,t1.`parents_id_number`,t1.`student_first_name`, 
    SUM(t1.`degree_value`) AS `values`,
    (SELECT `user_key`  
        FROM data_users.account_info t2 
        WHERE t1.id_number = t2.id_number AND t1.parents_id_number = t2.parents_id_number 
        LIMIT 1) AS `user_key`,
    (SELECT `first_name` 
        FROM data_users.account_info t2 
        WHERE t1.id_number = t2.id_number AND t1.parents_id_number = t2.parents_id_number 
        LIMIT 1) AS `first_name`,
    (SELECT `last_name` 
        FROM data_users.account_info t2 
        WHERE t1.id_number = t2.id_number AND t1.parents_id_number = t2.parents_id_number 
        LIMIT 1) AS `last_name`,
    (SELECT `about_me`  
        FROM data_users.account_info t2 
        WHERE t1.id_number = t2.id_number AND t1.parents_id_number = t2.parents_id_number 
        LIMIT 1) AS `about_me`
FROM `1479213957519` t1     
WHERE t1.year_half = '1' 
GROUP BY t1.`perfix` 
ORDER BY `Values` DESC 
LIMIT 6
```

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: If you have a table named 1479213957519 then the likelihood is that something's gone seriously wrong somewhere

Comment: thats auto generated table for post-data

Comment: Welcome @SaefMyth.  I see that you are new t the community.   Your post is, in my opinion, inadequate.  I voted to close this question because it is deemed OFFTOPIC by the community (see SO guidelines), since it does not present a problem that must be solved, but rather it requests coding support.  This is strictly off limits in SO.  Did not downvote because you are new to SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a join instead of correlated subqueries.

```
SELECT t1.`id_number`,t1.`parents_id_number`,t1.`student_first_name`, 
        SUM(t1.`degree_value`) AS `values`,
        t2.user_key, t2.first_name, t2.last_name, t2.about_me
FROM `1479213957519` t1
JOIN (SELECT *
      FROM data_users.account_info 
      GROUP BY id_number, parents_id_number) t2 
    ON t1.id_number = t2.id_number AND t1.parents_id_number = t2.parents_id_number
WHERE t1.year_half = '1' 
GROUP BY t1.`perfix` 
ORDER BY `Values` DESC 
LIMIT 6
```

If `id_number` and `parents_id_number` uniquely identifies a row in `account_info`, you don't need the subquery, you can just join with the table itself.

```
SELECT t1.`id_number`,t1.`parents_id_number`,t1.`student_first_name`, 
        SUM(t1.`degree_value`) AS `values`,
        t2.user_key, t2.first_name, t2.last_name, t2.about_me
FROM `1479213957519` t1
JOIN data_users.account_info  t2 
    ON t1.id_number = t2.id_number AND t1.parents_id_number = t2.parents_id_number
WHERE t1.year_half = '1' 
GROUP BY t1.`perfix` 
ORDER BY `Values` DESC 
LIMIT 6
```

Comment: perfcto man,,,the second Query took 0.0014 seconds,the first 0.263 , and mine took 0.334 ,, i need to learn more sql ,,, thanks dude